# how can i use process.env with github actions, runner, docker, ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, environment-variables, cicd

```
jobs:
  build:
    name: Build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Check out source code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set env
        run: |
          touch .env
          echo NEXT_PUBLIC_KAKAO_MAP_APP_KEY=${{ secrets.NEXT_PUBLIC_KAKAO_MAP_APP_KEY }} >> .env
          cat .env

      - name: Set up docker buildx
        id: buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v1

      - name: Cache docker layers
        uses: actions/cache@v2
        with:
          path: /tmp/.buildx-cache
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-buildx-${{ env.VERSION }}
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.os }}-buildx-

      - name: Login to ghcr
        uses: docker/login-action@v1
        with:
          registry: ghcr.io
          username: ${{ github.actor }}
          password: ${{ secrets.GHCR_TOKEN }}

      - name: Build and push
        id: docker_build
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
        with:
          builder: ${{ steps.buildx.outputs.name }}
          push: true
          tags: ${{ env.DOCKER_IMAGE }}:latest

  deploy:
    needs: build
    name: Deploy
    runs-on: [self-hosted, label-client]
    steps:
      - name: Login to ghcr
        uses: docker/login-action@v1
        with:
          registry: ghcr.io
          username: ${{ github.actor }}
          password: ${{ secrets.GHCR_TOKEN }}

      - name: Docker run
        run: |
          docker stop ${{ env.NAME }} && docker rm ${{ env.NAME }} && docker rmi ${{ env.DOCKER_IMAGE }}:latest
          docker run -d -p 80:3000 --name ${{ env.NAME }} --restart always ${{ env.DOCKER_IMAGE }}:latest
```

this is my workflow

Im distributing to ec2 using github action

Im using docker. However, even though I created the env file, the env file does not exist in the deployed image.

and .dockerignore is not working too.

I wrote README.md in .dockerignore, but README still exists

please help me..